# Visual Studio 2010 database project intellisense for SQL Server 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I have a Visual Studio 2010 database project for my SQL Server 2005 database.

It works fine and has intellisense when editing definition files for objects, but if I want to try running anything against the database as soon as the script file is connected I loose intellisense. I realise this is because Visual Studio is trying to use connection intellisense rather than from the schema of the project.

Is there anyway to force visual studio to always use the schmea of the project so that I can have intellisense all of the time?

Any solutions I have seen so far for this have required the use of a third party product to enable intellisense on SQL Server 2005, which is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like this can't be done.